# Default array value to class constructor angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

```
class DateComponent {
  constructor(public months:string[] = [],public days:number[] = [] , public years:number[] = []) { }

};
```

This is giving me error in Chrome. Says "=" is invalid. I am using angular 2 and typescript and webpack dev server.

How can i pass values to the parameters in constructor?

Comment: Why do you need it to be in constructor? You know that Angular2 is using Component's constructor specifically for DI purposes right?

Comment: Excatly what @HarryNinh says, [otherwise it looks fine](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20DateComponent%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20constructor(public%20months%3Astring%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B%5D%2Cpublic%20days%3Anumber%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B%5D%20%2C%20public%20years%3Anumber%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B%5D)%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D%3B).

Comment: Yes I get that ... but still if it is valid technically, why am I getting errors?

Answer (score 0):

Like Harry says in the comment, defining class members in the constructor is reserved for dependency injection in Angular 2.

I'd suggest moving those out of the constructor:

```
class DateComponent {
  public months: Array<string> = [];
  public days: Array<string> = [];
  public years: Array<string> = [];

  constructor() { 

  }
}
```

Comment: Yes I get that ... but still if it is valid technically, why am I getting errors?

Comment: and we can define and pass default value in the functions in typescript

Comment: Not in the constructor of a component, directive or a service you instantiate via DI.

Answer (score 0):

if you want optional parameter of constructor you must add "?". 
But the parameter of the object must define out of constructor.

In angular2 u will see that some parameter define in constructor but this have use in annotation (@Component, @Directive,...) that's define there as class property.

if i understand correct you want something like this:

```
class DateComponent {
      public months: [] = [];
      public days: [] = [];
      public years: [] = [];

      constructor(_months?:string[],_days?:number[], _years?:number[]) {
       this.months = _months;
       this.days = _days;
       this.years = _years;
     }

    };
```

Comment: No .. i want to define the elements of the class using the constructor and also pass the values there

Comment: why you want to do this in angular2 component?? 
could you send us a plunker or some more code??